# Повторный onclick

Tags: javascript

Если нажать на картинку, то она будет следовать за курсором. Но а как сделать так, чтобы при втором клике на картинку она бы уже отстала от курсора и стояла бы на том месте, на котором остановили, а при 3 клике она снова следовала за курсором и так далее.

Код:

```html
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  ns4 = (document.layers) ? true : false
  ie4 = (document.all) ? true : false

  function init() {
    if (ns4) {
      document.captureEvents(Event.onmousemove);
    }

    document.onmousemove = mousemove;
  }

  function mousemove(event) {
    var mouse_x = y = 0;
    if (document.attachEvent != null) {
      mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
      mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
    } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
      mouse_x = event.clientX;
      mouse_y = event.clientY;
    }
    status = "x = " + mouse_x + ", y = " + mouse_y;

    document.getElementById('x1').style.left = mouse_x;
    document.getElementById('x1').style.top = mouse_y;

  }
</script>

<body>
  <br>
  <div id="x1" style="position:absolute;width:50%;height:50%;" onclick="init()">
    <img src="2.JPG" width="189">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function init() {
  ...
  document.onmousemove = document.onmousemove? null : mousemove;
}
```

```js
ns4 = (document.layers) ? true : false
ie4 = (document.all) ? true : false

function init() {
  if (ns4) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.onmousemove);
  }

  document.onmousemove = document.onmousemove? null : mousemove;
}

function mousemove(event) {
  var mouse_x = 0;
  var mouse_y = 0;
  if (document.attachEvent != null) {
    mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
    mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
  } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
    mouse_x = event.clientX;
    mouse_y = event.clientY;
  }
  //console.log("x = " + mouse_x + ", y = " + mouse_y);

  document.getElementById('x1').style.left = mouse_x+"px";
  document.getElementById('x1').style.top = mouse_y+"px";

}
```

```css
#x1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id="x1" style="position:absolute;width:50%;height:50%;" onclick="init()">
  <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" width="189">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо! работает!